# How to change color of textviews with two button clicks

Tags: android

I have two textboxes,when i click button first time textview1's color should be changed and when i click on second time textview2's color should be changed.
How can i accomplish that in android.

Comment: Try to post some code. If you get errors we can help.

Comment: Actually i was looking for a logic...

Comment: Did you try the one I gave? And one thing I don't why I gave the code but this is not how its supposed to be. You post your code, tell us your error/problem and we help you resolve it. This is the way. But for now try what I have in my answer.

Comment: you've described the logic youself in your question. There is nothing to add there. The only thing left is to write code for it. What's a problem?

Comment: The problem is how can i count the clicks

Comment: I am new to android.Its been a 3-4 days i started android.that's why i don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a count at class level and check for its value.

***What this code does***: Every time you click the button it checks the value of counter and finds the remainder if divided by 2. On every second click remainder is 0 and second `TextView` color is changed otherwise first `TextView` color is changed.

Do this

```
int counter = 1;
TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_one);
TextView two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_two);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             if(counter % 2 == 0)
                 two.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000")); // change color as your need
             else 
                 one.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FFFF")); // change color as your need
             counter++;
         }
     });
```

Comment: It gives the error  for  view's objects: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable count inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: counter++:The final local variable count cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: Make it class level public variable. This is what I said in my answer. And don't make it final. `public int counter = 1;` at class level.

Comment: Perfect. Well don't forget to accept the answer then.  :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variable to store the click count in onClickListener of your button.. if it is clicked first time then set the color of text view if its value is two then do what you want...